# Find out the AES key from encrypted value + plaintext

Tags: encryption, cryptography, key, aes

I have two AES-enrypted tickets (see below) and the plaintexts to it. 
Can I find the AES key from this information?

encryption type:  AES CBC encryption with PKCS#5 padding

Two encrypted tickets:
CD46F0E2B829FBF75CA5A93D35CAF5FB3FFB997D7ADB606CD7F82DAE0D79859B84EA91D7D6A7F6FAF45C59DF370F1E31BEEF0000BEEF0000BEEF0000BEEF0000
Plaintext-value: 20101010

6B4CF1C63C819AA79437BEBF2189F672A40CB30AF1E8B2C7857A2C458DF8DFD286E898D4D6A7F6FAF66B67DD350D1C33BEEF0000BEEF0000BEEF0000BEEF0000
Plaintext-value: 20101209

Comment: Guess a key, check if it works, if not try again. Hope you're patient.

Answer (score 7):

The ability to determine the encryption key when one has access to one or more plaintexts and their associated ciphertexts is described as a "known-plaintext attack", to which ([according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack#Present_day)) AES is not (currently) known to be vulnerable.

Answer (score 3):

No! This is why AES is so strong and widely used. It was **designed** against this kind of attack.
ASE has not known weaknesses on.

- [Known plaintext attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack) (that what you ask for)
- [Chosen plaintext attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chosen-plaintext_attack) (you can pick messages that you want to encrypt)
- [Related-key attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Related-key_attack) (you can arbitrary change key, lets say increase key by 1)

Comment: AES-256 does have vulnerabilities w.r.t. related key attack due to weaknesses in the key schedule. They aren't *practical* when it comes to breaking AES when used as a cipher, but still. I strongly would advice to not just increase the key value, there are much better derivation methods available (in this case a ratchet would come close). Also, the description of what a chosen plaintext attack is wrong: it's the attacker that is trying to distinguish between ciphertext after encrypting a plaintext chosen by that same attacker (IND-CCA).

Answer (score 0):

Not without an amazing amount of luck.  Part of the purpose of strong cryptography like AES is to make doing what you propose mathematically infeasible.