# Finding encryption key

Tags: pdf, encryption, encryption-symmetric, cbc-mode

Given that you have an encrypted PDF document (that uses AES cbc mode encryption with single aes key used) and that you know first page of plaintext of the document (e.g. 150 words) that you can compare to the ciphertext, can you obtain the encryption key or in any case get access to the rest of the plaintext?

Comment: Yes, if you ask the person or entity responsible for the encrypted document to provide you the key. If you don't like to ask then you could brute force the password the key is derived from which might be illegal depending on your jurisdiction.

Comment: The plain text usually does not help because there are lots of ways to arrange instructions in content streams to draw the same appearance on screen.

Comment: Having the first 150 words is of no additional value in performing this operation. (The structure of PDF already gives you an abundance of cribs for validating decryption; a few more words don't matter.) The answer to your underlying question of whether there is a practical approach here, provided the encryption scheme is implemented correctly, the answer is no. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007246/find-out-the-aes-key-from-encrypted-value-plaintext?rq=1

Comment: All good ciphers, such as AES, can resist a Known Plaintext attack, which is what this is.  As @Artjom suggests your best bet is to ask the originator.  Alternatively a brute force attack will work, provided you can wait a few hundred years for your answer.